# VisualStudio 2015 не видит провайдер mySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Пытаюсь подключиться к MySQL. Установил пакеты MySQL.Data и (автоматически) MySQL.Data.Entity
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добавил провайдер, установил коннектор и мускл для студии и скомпилировал решение согласно этому мануалу https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264

Но студия не видит провайдер mySQL
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

проблема решается установкой вот этой версии MySQL for VS https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/